# Ubuntu desktop does not look the same after reinstalling ubuntu-desktop

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, restore

I messed up my Ubuntu's GUI and in an attempt to fix it installed Gnome desktop, instead of Ubuntu desktop. Once logged back into Ubuntu I realized that this is not what I expected. I ran the following with the hope to fix the issue:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

And restarted my computer. Now that I'm back I still see a lot of differences compared to the original GUI that I was using before that I do not like. For instance, Terminal does not have the nice purple color and **icons** for WiFi and other things on the top right and also the sidebar have been also changed. In addition, non of the files that I have in the **Desktop** directory are being shown on the desktop. So I'm pretty sure something is wrong still. By **right-clicking** on the desktop **nothing** shows up too. When I press the **Windows** key and look up different software names nothing shows up. The software names only show up if I click on the Unity icon and search their names on the sidebar I wonder, how can I really restore the original Ubuntu 14.04 GUI?

Here is how the terminal look now which I don't like:

[image]

**Update:** Since I have had this issue, I cannot run VirtualBox anymore and I get these errors when I try to run it:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix these problems?